# Booting a remoteproc on Linux boot or in the kernel device driver init

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I'd like to boot a remote processor on linux boot or boot it along with my kernel device driver.

I have a BeagleBone Black with a TI AM355x SoC, which has the main processor running `Debian 9.5 IoT armhf 2018-10-17` on a `4.14-ti` kernel and two PRU processors available through remoteproc. Remoteproc is active and the PRUs are available in sysfs under `/sys/class/remoteproc/remoteproc{1/2}/`. I can successfully boot the PRUs using the above interface.

I have tried:

- Setting an `rc.d` script which would boot the processors, but it seems that they're unavailable at the moment of its execution.
- Acquiring a `struct rproc` handle in my kernel module through the `struct rproc *rproc_get_by_phandle(phandle)` interface in `linux/remoteproc.h`, using the phandle defined in the DTB. Phandles are as such: `0x3` for the PRUSS, `0x8` for pru0, `0x9` for pru1. None of these work. Actually, I don't think any phandle works for this function.

I tried both `insmod` and adding the module to load on boot to `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)` and adding an entry in `/etc/modules`. Both versions failed retrieving the struct.

I can see that the linux headers from the 4.14-ti kernel have a `linux/pruss.h` file with a `pruss_get` function, but it takes a `struct rproc` as a parameter, therefore making me unable to use it.

rc.d script

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          config_pru
# Required-Start:    kmod
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Configure pins and launch pru
# Description:       
### END INIT INFO

config-pin P8_11 pruout
config-pin P8_15 pruin
config-pin P8_12 pruout
config-pin P8_16 pruin
echo am335x-pru0-fw > /sys/class/remoteproc/remoteproc1/firmware
echo start > /sys/class/remoteproc/remoteproc1/state
```

Fragment of the module file

```
static struct rproc *pru0_rproc;

(...)

static int get_pru0_rproc(void)
{
    pru0_rproc = rproc_get_by_phandle(0x3); // Both 0x8 0x9 doesn't work
    printk(KERN_INFO "rproc_get_by_phandle: trying 0x3");
    return -(pru0_rproc == NULL);
}

static int __init prusw_init(void)
{
    (...)
    if (get_pru0_rproc())
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "prusw: Failed to retrieve PRU0 rproc handle");
        goto deinit_rproc;
    }
    (...)
}
```

Decompiled dtb

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black", "ti,beaglebone-green";
part-number = "AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-14-TI";
version = "00A0";

fragment@0 {
    target-path = [2f 00];

    __overlay__ {

        ocp {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x1>;

            pruss_soc_bus@4a326004 {
                compatible = "ti,am3356-pruss-soc-bus";
                reg = <0x4a326004 0x4>;
                ti,hwmods = "pruss";
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                #size-cells = <0x1>;
                ranges = <0x0 0x4a3000
                status = "okay";
                 linux,phandle = <0x2>;
                 phandle = <0x2>;

                 pruss@0 {
                    compatible = "ti,am3356-pruss";
                    reg = <0x0 0x80000>;
                    interrupts = <0x14 0x15 0x16 0x17 0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b>;
                    interrupt-names = "host2", "host3", "host4", "host5", "hh
                ost6", "host7", "host8", "host9";
                    #address-cells = <0x1>;
                    #size-cells = <0x1>;
                    ranges;
                    status = "okay";
                    linux,phandle = <0x3>;
                    phandle = <0x3>;

                    (...)

                    pru@34000 {
                        compatible = "ti,am3356-pru";
                        reg = <0x34000 0x2000 0x22000 0x400 0x22400 0x100>;
                        reg-names = "iram", "control", "debug";
                        firmware-name = "am335x-pru0-fw";
                        interrupt-parent = <0x1>;
                        interrupts = <0x10 0x11>;
                        interrupt-names = "vring", "kick";
                        linux,phandle = <0x8>;
                        phandle = <0x8>;
                    };

                    pru@38000 {
                        compatible = "ti,am3356-pru";
                        reg = <0x38000 0x2000 0x24000 0x400 0x24400 0x100>;
                        reg-names = "iram", "control", "debug";
                        firmware-name = "am335x-pru1-fw";
                        interrupt-parent = <0x1>;
                        interrupts = <0x12 0x13>;
                        interrupt-names = "vring", "kick";
                        linux,phandle = <0x9>;
                        phandle = <0x9>;
                    };

                    (...)
```

I'm unable to boot any PRU in a non-manual way and I'd like to do it automatically on boot or kernel driver module load.

Comment: Just an idea - create a kernel module with a dependency on remoteproc module, and start PRU there?